# Proof of $\Bbb R$ is the unique complete linear order.

Tags: field-theory

I'm looking for the theorem that says that all linearly ordered, complete fields are isomorphic. I couldn't find references online, but I'm sure this theorem must have some name.

A link would be enough, thanks!

E: Let $X$ be a linearly ordered field. We say that $X$ is complete if for every bounded $E\subseteq X$, there exists an element $ x\in X$ such that $\sup E=x$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Edited: I meant in the sense of 'closed under $\sup$' (removed the redundant archimedean requirement).

Comment: here it is an order which is compatible with the field multiplication and addition, so the first thing is to show that it contains $\mathbb{Z},>$ and $\mathbb{Q},>$ and by completeness $\mathbb{R},>$. and the [Archimedean_property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property) seems to be a good hint for proving that there are no more elements.

Comment: [This PDF](http://spot.colorado.edu/~baggett/appendix.pdf) contains both a proof of the existence of a complete ordered field (via Dedekind cuts in $\Bbb Q$) and a proof that all such fields are isomorphic. It does assume that you know that an ordered field contains an isomorphic copy of $\Bbb Q$.